# Update database using Json object in java

Tags: java, android, mysql, json

I'm trying to update the location present in the database. The location is stored in the form of arraylist of cities containing their city id and city name. I am trying to make the app location aware. This function is called from the onCreate() method of the Home Frame Activity, if there is a change in the user's location. It would be great if you could go through this code and let me know if this is the process for updating the database or if there are any code changes that need to be made. As of now, even after detecting the user's current city (which was different from the user's registered city), and updating the city in the database using this function, the the different API's like callGeneralListAPI, callConnectAPI, etc use the old city id.

I have attached a screenshot of the log file which shows that even after retrieving the current city (Kolkata city id 7), the different APIs still use the old city id which was of Mumbai (City id 1).

Please let me know if I'm missing out on some code logic here.
Help would be appreciated.

<

```
private void setCurrentLocation() {

Log.i("info", "SETTING location FROM home FRAME ACTIVITY- SET CURRENT 

LOCATION");


Log.d("LOCATION", "LATITUDE=" + Double.toString(gpsTracker.getLatitude()));
Log.d("LOCATION", "longitude=" + 
Double.toString(gpsTracker.getLongitude()));

getLocationName(gpsTracker.getLatitude(), gpsTracker.getLongitude());

location = gpsTracker.getLocation();//the bug you pointed out
Log.d("LOCATION", "LATITUDE=" + Double.toString(location.getLatitude()));
Log.d("LOCATION", "longitude=" + Double.toString(location.getLongitude()));

Log.d("CITY NAME-", addressString);


if (location != null) {
    formList = AppController.getInstance().getFormList();
    ArrayList<String> citieList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Map<String, String> item : formList) {
        citieList.add(item.get("city"));
    }
    String[] citiesArray = citieList.toArray(new String[citieList.size()]);

    JSONObject locationChange = new JSONObject();
    try {
        if (addressString != null && !TextUtils.isEmpty(addressString)) {

            if (formList.indexOf(addressString) != -1) {
                CITY_ID = formList.indexOf(addressString) + 1;
                locationChange.put("userid", 
PreferenceManager.getInstance().getUserId());
                locationChange.put("location", CITY_ID);
                locationChange.put("location_lat", 
Double.toString(gpsTracker.getLatitude()));
                 locationChange.put("location_long", 
Double.toString(gpsTracker.getLongitude()));
                locationChange.put("connection", "0");

                Log.d(TAG, "LOCATION SET INTO DATABASE-INDEX OF ADDRESS 
STRING >1 " + locationChange);
                this.showProgressbar();
                RequestHandler.getInstance().postWithHeader(this, 
getString(R.string.baseurl) + getString(R.string.settings), locationChange, 
this, AppConstants.ApiRequestCodeKey.SAVE_APP_SETTINGS);

            }
            for (int i = 0; i < formList.size(); i++) {




  if(addressString.toLowerCase().contains(formList.get(i).get("city")
.toLowerCase())
)
                    CITY_ID = i + 1;// the id from the json file is (i+1)
            }
            locationChange.put("userid", 
PreferenceManager.getInstance().getUserId());
            locationChange.put("location", CITY_ID);
            locationChange.put("location_lat", 
Double.toString(gpsTracker.getLatitude()));
            locationChange.put("location_long", 
Double.toString(gpsTracker.getLongitude()));
            locationChange.put("connection", "0");

            Log.d(TAG, "LOCATION SET INTO DATABASE- INDEX OF ADDRESS STRING 
= -1 " + locationChange);
            this.showProgressbar();
            RequestHandler.getInstance().postWithHeader(this, 
getString(R.string.baseurl) + getString(R.string.settings), locationChange, 
this, AppConstants.ApiRequestCodeKey.SAVE_APP_SETTINGS
);

        }
    }
    catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

>

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9IPfI.png)

Comment: Does this change reflecting on server side?

Comment: what is this formList and how many entries it contain??

Comment: Well, that is the issue. It isn't bringing any changes in the database or on the server side. @Exigente05.

Comment: I have already answered possible debugging situations!

Comment: Well, formList contains all the details of of the user. It contains details like the name, username, email etc of the user. I'm not very sure of the exact number of entries.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should go through the following debugging procedure.

1. If possible catch a response for

`RequestHandler.getInstance().postWithHeader(this, 
getString(R.string.baseurl) + getString(R.string.settings), locationChange, 
this, AppConstants.ApiRequestCodeKey.SAVE_APP_SETTINGS`

either success or failed operation occurred. If failed then problem is there. And if success then,

2. Check where it is saving value in fact changing the desired value or not (I guess its not changing). If not changing then the problem is here. But if changing,
3. Check from where other API calling is fetching this value.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. However, I'm very new to android and very new to databases. Can you please tell me what exactly I need to do, to get a success response?

Comment: Problem with your mysql query. Check server side code carefully for updating city.